# Android Out of memory on custom listview

Tags: android, listview, memory, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

Hello the problem that I'm facing is that I have a custom list view with 7 Bitmap images included inside of it but when I attempt to scroll I receive an out of memory error, I have changed all images sizes and none of my images are even above 50kb. I have tried changing heap inside of the manifest but I was wondering if any had any recommendations. I have included the error in which was presented to me.

```
 Process: mycompany.myapplication, PID: 3275
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12006012 byte allocation with 2033536 free bytes and 1985KB until OOM
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:197)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:190)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:66)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:71)
```

The current adapter that I use to populate my listview

```
public class myAdapter extends ListFragment {


String[] liqueurs= {"Almond", "Cherry", "Chocolate Orange", "Lemon", "Orange", "Chocolate"};
String[] description = {
        "test",
        "With a delicious bite of fresh cherry, this can be drunk alone, or mixed with the Almond to make a Cherry Bakewell.",
        "Sweet, rich and smooth. Try it over ice-cream, cooked in a cake, or just sipped from a glass.",
        "Your classic Italian drink without the sharp finish. Absolutely delicious after dinner.",
        "Clean, fresh and with a sweet tang. Our orange liqueur is just the thing to wake your taste buds up.",
        "Made from real ground coco beans, surely this counts as 1 of your 5 a day"};
String[] prices = {"£7.99", "£7.99", "£7.99", "£7.99", "£7.99", "£7.99"};
int[] images ={R.drawable.almond, R.drawable.cherry, R.drawable.chocolateorange, R.drawable.lemon, R.drawable.orange, R.drawable.chocolate};


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
SimpleAdapter adapter;

public LiqueuresAdapter() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment




    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String> ();





    for(int i=0;i<liqueurs.length;i++){

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("liqueurs",liqueurs[i]);
        map.put("description", description[i]);
        map.put("prices", prices[i]);
        map.put("Image", Integer.toString(images[i]));

        data.add(map);


    }

    String[] from = {"liqueurs", "Image", "description", "prices"};



    int[] to={R.id.wineName, R.id.wineImage, R.id.wineDes, R.id.winePrice};

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), data, R.layout.custom_winelist, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);



    //  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_us, container, false);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);



}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}


// Removes duplicate id error by destroying the container and rebuilding it when next selected
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    Fragment xmlFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (xmlFragment != null) {
        fm.beginTransaction().remove(xmlFragment).commit();
    }

    super.onDestroyView();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to use Glide or Picasso to load, cache and manage the images, and also you can use the ViewHolder design pattern to optimize your ListView performace and reduce the load in memory. Basically what the ViewHolder does is to reuse the views without inflating new ones (which increases the memory).
This might lower your memory.
[Here](https://github.com/isaacurbina/ViewHolderListView) is an example in my GitHub account of how to customize the ArrayAdapter in a ListView to incorporate the ViewHolder.
I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Isaac I have downloaded your project and it was very useful, it was interesting to see how you got it work with JSON. After looking at the array adapter class would it possible to change your code so it looks at my arrays which I have stated above?

Comment: Yes it's possible, I'll give it a look on the weekend

Comment: Thats ok I have been looking up view holders since your message and I think I have sorted the problem :D